# Failed to load javascript script in Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I wrote a javascript script for `script_score` in `function_score`, but I get the following error on elasticsearch service start. I am running Ubuntu 14.04, elasticsearch 1.4.5. I sadly cannot post the code here.

What would constitute a valid return value? Is there any way to debug the score script or print to elasticsearch logs?

> [2015-05-23 21:00:18,093][INFO ][script                   ] [Soulfire] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/****.js]
>   [2015-05-23 21:00:18,180][WARN ][script                   ] [Soulfire] failed to load/compile script [****]
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: invalid return (Script1.js#14)

Thanks

#### Update:

I tried a script with just `return 0.5;`. I still get the error:

> [2015-05-23 22:52:48,527][INFO ][script                   ] [Warrior Woman] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/test.js]
>   [2015-05-23 22:52:48,609][WARN ][script                   ] [Warrior Woman] failed to load/compile script [test]
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: invalid return (Script1.js#1)

#### Update 2:

I removed the `return` keyword from my script, e.g:
`return 0;` becomes `0;`

This results in the errors subsiding, but I continue to get unexpected results. I would still like to know how I can log from within the js script.

Comment: I would suggest reproducing the issue in a script that you can post here, otherwise it's just guesswork

Answer (score 0):

From the quick look on the log,ES is trying to say it is unable to load or compile your Javascript script.Also please add more info, if this is your dynamic script or standalone script stored in script files on host.
If you have't installed javascript-lang plugin for ES, there is no way ES can compile and run your Javascript.You must take a look at the following link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Even groovy is now no more sandboxed for dynamic scripting because of security concerns with ES 1.5.0 + as ES people have comeup with their own security module.

revert back if my answer gave you any help.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, this is a standalone script as the logs too indicate 
- "/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/****.js".

`lang-javascript` plugin is installed. I just got rid of the error by removing the `return` keyword. But I'm not sure how my script is working now. I'd really like to know if I can log messages from within the js script.

Comment: there must be some setting in logging.yml file to turn on debug or trace for script.